# Bounding box of the recognized symbols using python-tesseract - wrong (overlapped) coordinates?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to make OCR of the picture and need to get also coordinates of all the recognized symbols.

I can do that successfully using pytesseract.image_to_boxes, but pretty often the coordinates in the result are bad:

- either right edge of the previous symbol has bigger coordinate than the beginning of the next one
- or the beginning of the next symbol showing earlier

As result, I am getting the overlapping of the boxes.

Here is the picture, where I can show you such problem:

[image]

The code is:

```
filename = "page_1 - Copy.jpg"

page_width, page_height = Image.open(filename).size
print(page_width, page_height)

symbols_from_page = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(Image.open(filename),lang='deu', output_type=Output.DICT)#,boxes=True,config='hocr')

n_symbols = len(symbols_from_page['char'])
for i in range(n_symbols):
    #print(d['char'][i])
    (val,x, y, r, b, w, h) = (symbols_from_page['char'][i], symbols_from_page['left'][i], page_height - symbols_from_page['top'][i], symbols_from_page['right'][i] \
                              , page_height - symbols_from_page['bottom'][i], symbols_from_page['right'][i] - symbols_from_page['left'][i], symbols_from_page['top'][i] - symbols_from_page['bottom'][i])
    print(val,x, y, r, b, w, h)
```

And the results:

```
256 149

E 8 107 16 123 8 16
i 19 112 20 123 1 11
n 24 111 31 122 7 11
e 34 111 42 123 8 12
s 50 111 57 123 7 12
t 58 109 64 123 6 14
a 65 111 73 123 8 12
r 76 111 81 122 5 11
k 83 107 90 123 7 16
e 93 111 101 123 8 12
G 109 106 118 123 9 17
e 122 111 129 123 7 12
m 132 111 145 122 13 11
e 140 106 152 123 12 17
i 148 111 161 123 13 12
n 164 111 172 123 8 12
s 174 111 182 123 8 12
c 184 111 192 123 8 12
h 195 107 203 122 8 15
a 200 106 209 123 9 17
f 206 111 213 123 7 12
t 215 107 227 123 12 16
```

The problem is withthe 4th and 3rd symbols from the end:
"h" has right coordinate (203) bigger, than left coordinate (200) of the next symbol "a".

Did I do something wrong here? May be my understanding of these boxes is a bit wrong?
Or the library has any bugs?

Thank you for any advice!